# How can i use the bool variables in logical way when the character collide the box?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoxCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    private float degrees = 180f;
    public float rotateSpeed = 10f;
    private GameObject character;
    private bool entered = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        if (entered == true)
        {
            character.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(character.transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(degrees, 0, degrees), rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
    {
        character = c.gameObject;        
        entered = true;
    }
}
```

On the first time the character collide a wall (empty gameobject with a box collider ) it's changing the entered to true and rotating the character.

But on colliding with the other wall after rotated and reached the other wall i used a breakpoint and it's getting to the part:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider c)
        {
            character = c.gameObject;        
            entered = true;
        }
```

But then when it's getting to the Update function:

```
if (entered == true)
```

I used a breakpoint on this line and entered is false.
Not sure why.

On the first collide with a wall it's true but on the second collide with a wall it's false.

The reason i'm using this bool is to rotate the character only when collide a wall(box).

I have 4 empty gameobjects around the terrain each one of them have a box collider istrigger is set to on and also this script is attached to every gameobject.

I can't figure out why first time entered is true second time it's false.

Comment: Sure you're seeing/debuging the correct entity? (Often breakpoints in multiple times used objects are confusing if not misleading.)

Answer (score 1):

Either the OnTriggerEnter is not working (If you're colliding with walls, don't you want [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)?) or you have some other script that sets `entered` to false. Because according to the code you sent once you Enter a Collider that is set to isTrigger `entered` will always be true. Ensure that you haven't attached the script to many objects. This could also give you misleading debugging values since it may be false on another object.

Also worth noting...

> Notes: Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached.

Or if you're using a CharacterController. If you have ANY code that sets `entered` to false you should and must include that for further help.

Comment: Still not working. The script is attached to each of the 4 empty gameobjects with the box collider component added to each gameobject. So the script is in 4 places attached on each gameobject. And the ThirdPersonController (1) i have two ThirdPersonControllers . I have on it this components: Animator, Rigidbody, Capsule Collider, Third Person User Control (Script), Third Person Character (Script) That's all. In the Rigidbody the Use Gravity is checked(set to on).

Comment: Every wall is spinning the player once they collided with player... Are you sure there are no code that sets `entered` to false?

Comment: Not working yet. But i did some tests. I see that when it's getting to the update function after collided with the first wall in the Inspector on the wall colided with the character i see the checkbox of entered checked so it's true. And then after rotated it's moving to the second wall and i see that this wall the checkbox near entered is unchecked false but it's still checked true in the first wall. Then it's touching the second wall and it's checkbox near entered also checked. So now both walls entered is checked it's true. But yet it's not rotating back on the second wall.

Comment: Why would it rotate back?

Comment: It should rotate back on the second collide no ? Why not ? The first wall it collide rotating 180 degrees then on the next collide with the second wall it should rotate again 180 degrees. back to the other side. I think this is the logic. And even if it's not should rotating back why it keep walking out of the terrain ? It should at least keep walking on place since the wall should stop it from being keep moving out the terrain.

Comment: What you've coded is: If player touch a wall, spin forever. There is no code to make player stop spinning? There is no code that says `entered = false`

Comment: I tried to add entered = false; inside the update function after the Quaternion.Slerp line. But when doing this the character on the first wall colide just change rotate by maybe 10-20 degrees and keep moving out the terrain. It seems that when it's getting to the update function and make the Quaternion.Slerp line it's doing it few times before the rotation is completed. I used a breakpoint few minutes ago and it's entering few times to the line Quaternion.Slerp when colliding with the first wall.

Comment: That wont work, you will stop the rotation after 1 frame. Hmm... When I use your code it spins to -180 then stops, which is correct. Are you telling me that it keeps spinning for you? It wont rotate back because it's already at the position it wants to rotate to.

Comment: Then i mixed it all maybe. What i want to do is each time it's colliding with a wall so turn back and walk on the way he came from.

Comment: In my code when it touch the first wall it's turning back on the way he came from it's spinning once 180 degrees. But on the second wall it's not stopping and not spinning back he keep walking like there is no wall. Even if i see while the game is running that on the second wall collide the checkbox near entered is checked but yet it's not spinning back and the wall not stopping the character.

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Comment: What you want to do is to, instead of setting it to a hardcoded 180 degrees, you want to take current rotation of player when player enters the trigger and add 180 to it. Because right now, every time you collide you say "rotate TO 180 degrees" instead of "rotate another 180 degrees"

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand it sooner :D

Comment: You can set `float degrees = 0` in the top and then `degrees = degrees+180` in OnTriggerEnter. Should work like you want it. But it will be weird when you have many objects that wants to rotate player. You should probably make a Coroutine that sets entered to false. `StartCoroutine(MakeEnteredFalse());` in OnTriggerEnter and then a new method: `IEnumerator MakeEnteredFalse() { yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); entered = false; } `